# How to clone JRResultSetDataSource?

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports

Am using subreport, my subreport data source is a JRResultSetDataSource. The details are displayed in the first row but not in the second row. To display the second row I need to clone the datasource. How to clone a resultset datasource?

Am developing this using JDBC. Kindly advise me.

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I guess to display next result you need to call `next()` on `JRResultSetDataSource`

Comment: I think you are doing something else wrong. You shouldn't need to do anything else other than pass the `JRResultSetDatasource` to the sub-report. Are you getting any exceptions? Can you post the java code you use to call the report?